# ctrl + click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, click, ctrl

I have browsed the internet extensively on this issue, including stackoverflow.
My problem is that I have a set of 'li', and I want multiple 'li' added to an array when I use ctrl+click gesture. I keep on getting (e) is not defined. I have found this: [Detect CTRL and SHIFT key without keydown event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316509/detect-ctrl-and-shift-key-without-keydown-event)

But the answer provided, which seems to have worked for many, doesn't for me. Whenever I use that, even as the sole item in my script, firebug doesn't respond in the console, but I get: " ReferenceError: e is not defined." I'm using Firefox.

My biggest problem is getting this to add this to a function, and the function, which fires as an event, can distinguish between the a ctrl+click and normal click.

Any expertise to help me out? Vanilla Javascript preferred.

The point of this exercise is to remove the LI when clicked, but I want to delete multiple at once if I hold down ctrl. Perhaps by storing them in an array.
EDIT: Some Code

```
    <ul id = "ulItem">
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
<li>item4</li>
</ul>

<script>

window.onload = function(){
var ulItem = document.getElementById("ulItem"); //gets UL with the "ulItem" ID.
var ulList = ulItem.getElementsByTagName("li"); //gets ulItem's "li" in an array.



///prepareLI function.///
var prepareLi = function(){

for(i = 0; i < ulList.length; i++){

ulList[i].addEventListener('click', elementClick);
}
}

//adds the same event listener to each of the "li" inside "UlList" array. Each activated by a click.




///elementClick function.///

var elementClick = function(){

ulItem.removeChild(this);

} //if this is a child of parent, UlList, remove it.

prepareLi();
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code so far? (preferably in a fiddle or something similar)

Comment: @mookamafoob Preferably *not* in a fiddle; code has to go in the question or the question should be closed.

Comment: Actually :) post here your code, the fiddle is just if you want us to visualize the issue and get fast a reliable answer.

Comment: @meagar I didn't mean exclusively in a fiddle :P but an example is easier to debug

Comment: @mookamafoob Words have meaning. When you say he should post his code, preferably in a fiddle, it implies *only* in a fiddle. If anything he should post his code exclusively in his question. Nobody should be required to produce a working fiddle to get help here.

Comment: Here's a quick fiddle that may or may not help. http://jsfiddle.net/Dd3mS/1/ Let us know a little more and we can be more specific :)

Comment: Hey, I'm gonna check out that fiddle and see if I can apply it to my code somehow. For those asking for example code, I couldn't get it to work on fiddle, but I pasted the "body" of the HTML in my OP. It works , but isn't capable of the multiple selection I want to make when hitting ctrl.

Comment: Your `elementClick` function doesn't accept any arguments. You did not follow the example in [Detect CTRL and SHIFT key without keydown event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316509/detect-ctrl-and-shift-key-without-keydown-event) correctly. The example there has `function(e) { ... }`, where yours is `function() { ... }`. That's why your get a message that `e is not defined`: the example defines `e` as an argument, but your code never defines `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an alternative way to do this.
If you want to emulate a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click in order to select multiple objects, this worked for me as a workaround:

make two variables, loader and loaderArray:

```
var loader = 1;
var loaderArray = [];
```

set a document event:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', MultiSelect);
```

and a click event on the item:

```
document.addEventListener('click', singleSelect);
```

Make sure the window event is is a `mousedown` item, also, that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is defined as `keyCode == 17`. The number part is VERY important. Here is code I used:

```
    function loadArray(e) {

        if (e.keyCode === 17) {

            //console.log("key down");

            loader = 2;

        };

    }
```

Then I set a separate function on the singleSelect event stating that if `loader ==2`, use `loaderArray.push(this)` rather than the normal way of doing things when `loader == 1`. 
The loader Array then collects the variables, and you can do whatever you want with the array using `for()` or some other loop.

Now, whenever I click the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, the mousevent on the document turns the loader variable to 2, and it can distinguish between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click and normal click this way.

Thanks for all those that helped, and I hope this will help others! :)

Answer (score 7):

The browser is correctly telling you that you never declared `e`, while the example in [Detect CTRL and SHIFT key without keydown event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316509/detect-ctrl-and-shift-key-without-keydown-event) has defined `e`, by declaring it as a formal argument to the listener function.

```
var elementClick = function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey) {
        ulItem.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

Note the use of `function(e){` rather than `function(){`

Comment: To support mac you also should check for `|| e.metaKey`