# Key pressed and click in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I merge keypress and on click? I mean when a user press enter and click somewhere in the same time I need to invoke a function.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 13) {
        alert('keypress');
    }
});
$(document).on( "click", function() {
    alert('click');
});
```

I have this code but I am not able to merge it (usually I don't work with jQuery/javascript).

Comment: Flag the keydown if it's ENTER (unflag on keyup), and check the flag in click handler. Some [special keys can be detected](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317134/1169519) also in a click handler directly.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to react on a click **while** the enter key is pressed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this may do the trick

```
var pressingEnter = false;
$(document).on({
    keydown: function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            // enter is being pressed, set true to flag variable
            pressingEnter = true;
        }
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            // enter is no longer pressed, set false to flag variable
            pressingEnter = false;
        }
    },
    click: function() {
        if (pressingEnter) {
           console.log('click and enter pressed');
        }
    }
});
```

BTW: there is no need to do `var code = e.keyCode || e.which;` since jQuery resolves that for you. You can use `e.which` on any browser.

**EDIT**

This version should allow any order of key pressed / mouse click. I'm assuming only left click is captured. Logic to handle enter + mouse click is placed on `keydown` and `mousedown` (it could be moved to `keyup` and `mouseup` if makes more sense)

Changed `alert`  by `console.log` since the first prevents `mouseup` event to be triggered. Nowdays we have hundred of better ways to show a message to user than built-in alert pop ups so I'll assume making it work for it is not a requirement.

```
var pressingEnter = false;
var clickingMouseButton = false;
$(document).on({
    keydown: function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            pressingEnter = true;
        }

        if (clickAndEnterPressing()) {
            console.log('click and enter pressed');
        }        
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            pressingEnter = false;
        }
    },
    mousedown: function(e) {
        if (e.which == 1) {
            clickingMouseButton = true;
        }

        if (clickAndEnterPressing()) {
            console.log('click and enter pressed');
        }           
    },
    mouseup: function(e) {
        if (e.which == 1) {
            clickingMouseButton = false;
        }
    }
});

function clickAndEnterPressing() {
    return pressingEnter && clickingMouseButton;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that will work if enter is pushed first or if the mouse is clicked first or if they are both pressed within a certain threshold of time apart (I set it to 100 ms, but this can be easily adjusted):

```
var enterDown = false;
var mouseDown = false;
var lastEnter = false;
var lastMouseUp = false;

var triggerOnNextUp = false;
$(document).on({
    keydown: function(e) {
        enterDown = true;
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            lastEnter = (new Date()).getTime();
            enterDown = false;
            detectEnterAndClick();
            if (mouseDown) {
                triggerOnNextUp = true;
            }
        }
    },
    mousedown: function() {
        mouseDown = true;
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        lastMouseUp = (new Date()).getTime();
        mouseDown = false;
        detectEnterAndClick();
        if (enterDown) {
            triggerOnNextUp = true;
        }
    }
});

function detectEnterAndClick() {
    if (Math.abs(lastEnter - lastMouseUp) < 100 || triggerOnNextUp) {
        // Reset variables to prevent from firing twice
        triggerOnNextUp = false;
        enterDown = false;
        mouseDown = false;
        lastEnter = false;
        lastMouseUp = false;

        $("body").append("Clicked and pushed enter<br>");
    }
}
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8osexhy/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 'merge' events. However you could for example [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce) your handler. For example (using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)):

```
var handler = _.debounce(function(event) { alert(event.type); }, 100);
$(document)
  .on('click', handler)
  .on('keypress', handler);
```

Comment: Note, this solutions requires the use of the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but they look like two different libraries.

Comment: Lodash and underscore have similar functinality, but there are _slight_ [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789618/differences-between-lodash-and-underscore#answer-13898916)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the event.type to determine what triggered the event

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwbjvR)**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ClickAndKeyPress);

  $(document).on("keypress", ClickAndKeyPress);
});


function ClickAndKeyPress(event){
  $("div").text(event.type);
}
```